# Conditional formatting based on another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a column on sheet1 with a list of names. I need conditional formatting on it to turn it red if that name does not show up **anywhere** on sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

> =countif(indirect("sheet2!$A:$M"),$A1)=0

I'm not sure how to make it not color blanks though.